# MATLAB - Can you do a multiple histogram figure?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I want to make multiple plots of a histogram in one figure, like the subplot command, only with histograms. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In different subplots?

```
subplot(2,1,1)
hist(...)
subplot(2,1,2)
hist(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to put multiple histograms in one figure using hold on. However, you'll need to change the color for the first histogram before you plot the next one.

```
x1 = randn(1000,1);x2 = 1 + randn(1000,1);
hist(x1,100), hold on
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'FaceColor','r','Edgecolor','c')
hist(x2,100)
```

You should take caution when comparing the histograms though, since the histogram bins are generated separately.

I use the following additions to resolve this:

```
x1 = randn(1000,1);x2 = 1 + randn(1000,1);
xrangel = min(min(x1),min(x2));
xrangeh = max(max(x1),max(x2));
x1_tmp = x1(x1>=xrangel & x1<=xrangeh);
x2_tmp = x2(x2>=xrangel & x2<=xrangeh);
xbins = xrangel:(xrangeh - xrangel)/res:xrangeh;
hist(x1_tmp,xbins)
hold on 
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
% some additional coloring to help visibility
set(h,'FaceColor','c','EdgeColor',[0 0.99 0],'LineWidth',1.2,'LineStyle','-','EdgeAlpha',0.89);
hist(x2_tmp,xbins)
```